# Docker networking - Keycloak can not connect to postgresql running in separate docker instance

Tags: postgresql, docker, keycloak

I have two docker containers, one running Keycloak 4.7.0.Final, and one running Postgresql.

Keycloak Dockerfile

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:4.7.0.Final

ADD themes/mytheme /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/healthjoiner

ADD modules /opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak
ADD standalone-ha.xml /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/
ADD keycloak-config.json /opt/jboss/

RUN mkdir -p $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/data

CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0", "-Dkeycloak.migration.action=import -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile -Dkeycloak.migration.file=/opt/jboss/keycloak-config.json -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING"]
```

Postgres Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:9.5

# set root user details
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres

ADD scripts/init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

# expose the 5432 port to outside the container
EXPOSE 5432
```

Here is a the problematic section within the standalone-ha.xml file, specifically the `connection-url` value.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:5.0">
        <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true"
                        use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://my-net/keycloak</connection-url>
            <driver>postgresql</driver>
            <pool>
                <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
            </pool>
            <security>
                <user-name>keycloak</user-name>
                <password>sa</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql">
                <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
    </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

Postgres starts fine. When I start Keycloak I get `java.net.UnknownHostException: my-net`. I have also tried `localhost` and get the same error.

Lastly I have created a user-defined bridge network as per the guide on [docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/#use-user-defined-bridge-networks)

```
docker network create --driver bridge my-net
```

I followed the guide but I can't get keycloak to find the postgresql database. From my understanding, the network `my-net` should be available internally to the container running keycloak.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

### UPDATE

Postgres was started with the following:

```
docker run --name postgresql -p 5432:5432 --network my-net postgresql
```

And keycloak with:

```
docker run --name keycloak -p 8080:8180 --network my-net keycloak
```

Comment: How did you start containers? I would like to see the network and name configuration of your containers.

Comment: Do you need to modify the xml file for connecting to postgres? Could you just follow the official docker-compose example https://github.com/jboss-dockerfiles/keycloak/blob/master/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-postgres.yml ?

Comment: @RyanDawson I did try that also but it was not successful, however i am not using docker compose at this point. I added these db values as ENV properties in the Dockerfile

Comment: @JanGaraj I have updated the question to include the command I use to start the containers. I think this is what you were asking for?

Comment: I would use docker-compose with __links__ option for this, then the connection-url will be __jdbc:postgresql://postgres_service_name__ . Also default network would be created by docker-compose.

Comment: Well, as I search across any solution to my Keycloak container not connecting to my PostgreSQL container, the `--name` did the trick. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation: don't create your own Docker image only for the theme/modules. Use official Keycloak image and mount your custom files as a volume => you will have easier image update. The official image also offers DB config env variables, so you won't need to use a customized config file:

```
docker run -d \
  --name keycloak \
  --net my-net \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -p 443:8443 \
  -v $PWD/themes/mytheme:/opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/healthjoiner \
  -v $PWD/modules:/opt/jboss/keycloak/modules/system/layers/keycloak \
  -e DB_VENDOR=postgres \
  -e DB_ADDR=postgresql \
  -e DB_PORT=5432 \
  -e DB_DATABASE=<DB> \
  -e DB_USER=<DBUSER> \
  -e DB_PASSWORD=<DBPASSWORD> \
  jboss/keycloak:4.7.0.Final
```

See doc: https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak

Anyway connection URL in your case is (use only container name):

```
jdbc:postgresql://keycloak:5432/<DATABASE>
```